# Rewrite Rule https://www to https:// IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, ssl, url-rewriting, ssl-certificate

I’ve received my ssl certificate on a shared hosting provided and installed it successfully. The certificate is prepared for mysite.com, not for *.mysite.com.
I want the site to be accessible like https : // mysite.com – no www, no http (only secure connections). I've found similar questions here, but not the right one.
I'm using IIS 7, .net environment. The following rules were added my web.config:

```
<rule name="Remove WWW prefix">
<match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mysite\.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="443" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https:// mysite.com/{R:1}" />
```

Everything is working fine, but the url https://www.mysite.com is not redirected to https://mysite.com. I get the error that the certificate is for mysite.com (which was intended :), the message comes from firefox) with the advice to add exception.

My question is what is the appropriate rule for this url?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you can do this. You need a valid SSL certificate on https://www.mysite.com to get redirected to https://mysite.com without warning the user about an invalid certificate. IIS will attempt to negotiate the SSL connection before URL Rewrite has a chance to act on it.

You could possibly do this with a DNS entry. You could add a CNAME entry that looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com.   CNAME   mysite.com.
```

Comment: Exactly -- browser will display the warning message before connection will be fully established.

Comment: OK, I understand this. I might be wrong but is it possible to make some DNS redirect or even better if this is an error I could handle with specific page(which again makes redirect)?

Comment: thanks a lot, I've already requsted this change and in a day or two we will know if this works :)

Comment: it didn't happen that way either. I had an A record like the one you advised me to add, I replaced it with the cname. The change took effect very quickly but again I wasn't redirected to https : // mysite.com. I appreciate your efforts. In summary: for now I couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry, I think I misread your post! I have given you a rule to go from http to https automatically. I'll leave it here in case it helps someone else who (like me) also can't read and you could tweak it to make it fit your case.

Read this post by Omar Al Zabir: http://omaralzabir.com/redirecting-traffic-from-http-to-https-with-zero-coding-in-iis/

And then see my (Tom Chantler) comment to his post.

Comment: Appreciate this is an old question however the above instructions worked perfectly for me.  In addition, any further bindings that need redirecting can be added to the dummy site (e.g. www.mysite.com) which will then also redirect to the domain specified which would solve the OPs question

Answer (score 1):

Those 2 rules worked for me.

```
    <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://mysite.com{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

Additional reading:

http://www.jppinto.com/2010/03/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-on-iis7-using-url-rewrite-2-0/

http://keyvan.io/remove-www-prefix-from-urls-with-url-rewrite-module-for-iis-7-0